# Cannot import SVG dynamic using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I tried the below code to import SVG dynamically.

```
let selectedFloor = require('../svg/floor1.svg');
this.setState({
  SvgMap : selectedFloor
})

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.state.SvgMap }} />
    </div>
  );
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: show your state pls

Comment: You probably need to look into whatever you're using to transpile your `js`. For example if you're using `webpack` you may need to setup a loader to handle `svg` and make it part of your built app.

Comment: thanks for you replay, this is constructor :
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      SvgMap :""
    }      
}

Comment: why not using <img src="../svg/floor1.svg" /> ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using like this:

```
<span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: `<img src=${this.state.SvgMap} />` }} />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the `img` tag, and you can keep the path to the SVG file in the state, or only the name.

```
const selectedFloor = 'floor1.svg';
this.setState({
    SvgMap : selectedFloor
});

render() {   
    return (
      <div>
          <img src={`../svg/${this.state.SvgMap}`}
      </div>
    );
}
```